# Average different layers in a Array without considering NaN value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, mean

I have masked array data in three layer (accessing from `NetCDF` file), which is given below. I want to **mean** these three layer without considering `NaN` value (**Here -1**) cell while averaging. Any suggestion will be helpful.

```
masked_array(

      data=[[ 270,  554, -1],
            [ 270,  -1, 2068],
            [ -1,  554, 2068],
        ...,
        [ -1, -1, 1349],
        [ 704, 1019, -1],
        [ 704, 1019, 1349]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=999999,
  dtype=int16)
```

Output Should be like this:

```
  data=[[412],
        [1169],
        [1311],
        ...,
        [1349],
        [861.5],
        [1536]]
```

Comment: provide minimum reproducible example

Comment: For initial implement you can use first three 3 rows to apply your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pythonic way:

```
import numpy as np

# get data from masked array
d = np.ma.getdata(masked_array)

# get the mean
masked_mean = [row[row!=-1].mean() for row in d]
```

Comment: I have tried this, but error occured. **TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array**. Suggest me for same.

Comment: In which line? Try to check your masked_array if it's displaying correctly or not.

Comment: It's displaying same as I have mentioned in a Question.

Comment: Even i tried with `np.ma.masked_array()` to open variable.

Comment: It is working fine for me. Maybe you should check masked_array for any ambiguous rows. Or provide code to produce your masked_array to debug it properly.

Comment: Ok i will try. Thank you for the discussion and suggestion.